# How do I access angular scope values during directive link phase?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an element that shows a datetimepicker. It is timezone sensitive. The time is stored in an `item` object in the scope as `item.time`, while the TZ is stored as `item.timezone`.

I created a directive to render it. In order to actually render correctly, it needs to know the timezone, but at link time (when it is all processed), the controller has not yet correctly loaded item... or so I would think, but it has correctly loaded `item`, because `item.time` is there. Nonetheless, when the formatter gets called, it has `attrs.timezone` as "", even though `modelValue` is loaded correctly.

HTML:

```
<span datetimepicker="true" ng-model="item.time" timezone="{{item.timezone}}"></span>
```

And the JS, (leaving out most of it...)

```
    .directive('datetimepicker',function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        template: '<span><input readonly="readonly"></input><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>',
        replace: true,
        link: function ($scope,element,attrs,ngModel) {
            var format = "YYYY-MM-DD H:mm",
            formatter = function (modelValue) {
                // HERE IS MY PROBLEM: at this point, modelValue does == item.time, but attrs.timezone is "", even though I know it loads correctly!
                var ret = modelValue ? moment(modelValue) : "", mtz;
                if (ret.tz) {
                    mtz = ret.tz(attrs.timezone);
                }
                if (mtz) {
                    ret = mtz.format(format);
                } else if (ret.format) {
                    ret = ret.format(format);
                }
                return ret;
            };
    ngModel.$formatters.push(formatter);
    };
})
```

EDIT:

angular is properly evaluating the attr "timezone" on the element; it is just not available inside the link function, or even the formatter. Here is the html after loading:

```
<span timezone="America/Winnipeg" ng-model="item.time" datetimepicker="true" class="ng-valid ng-valid-datetime ng-dirty">
   <input readonly="readonly"/><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar">
</span>
```

EDIT: add controller, highly simplified

```
    .controller('ItemDetail',['$scope','Item',
    function ($scope,Item) {
        var itemId = "40"; // not really, but good enough for here
        Item.get({item: itemId},function (item) {
            $scope.item = item;
        },function (httpResponse) {
            // do error reporting
        });
        // click button to enter edit mode, which hides <span> showing time and shows input with datepicker
        $scope.edit = function () {
            $scope.editMode = true;
        };
        $scope.save = function () {
            // save the updates
            $scope.item.$save();
            $scope.editMode = false;
        };
        $scope.cancel = function () {
            // cancel any updates
            $scope.item.$reset();
            $scope.editMode = false;
        };
    }])
```

Comment: Does it have anything to do with the fact that you refer to the time zone property on `item` as `item.tz` in one place, the you bind to `item.timezone` in your attribute binding?

Comment: @jdmcnair I wish, but that was just sloppy copying into stackoverflow on my part. In the actual code, it is `item.timezone` all the way through.

Comment: Can you give me your controller? or full code with plunker

Comment: Sure. Editing up top.

Comment: Controller added. Nothing too fancy, just loads an `Item`

Comment: can pass it to isolated scope property of directive, or you could use `attrs.$observe()` to wait for value to be set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use an isolate scope, bind the scope var through attribute bindings (= binding), and use `scope.$watch`to set the timezone with a callback:

```
// directive scope binding
scope: {
  timezone: '='
}

// watch local scope var in the link function since it's now binded
scope.$watch('timezone',function(newval, oldval){
  // do what you need to do from here when the timezone var gets set
  mtz = ret.tz(attrs.timezone);
});
```

[More information on scope bindings](https://umur.io/angularjs-directives-using-isolated-scope-with-attributes/)

Comment: This is pretty close. I don't even need an isolated scope; it is enough that I can do `<span timezone="item.timezone">` and then just `scope.$watch(attrs.timezone,function(){...});` although isolated scope works as well. But how would I then re-trigger the formatter?

Comment: Well if you're formatter depends on this value, I would just create and add the formatter inside the `$watch`. It is up to you to decide if your users should be able to edit while the formatters are loading or possibly make and push two different formatters if both formatters have independent async dependencies.

Comment: also to your point above, i like to explictly declare (isolate scope bindings) my directive dependancies because I think it's cleaner and less confusing.

Comment: I can see that, although it can get confusing as I pass the Item back up to be saved.

Comment: Fair, but you can also use scope function bindings. Either way it all depends on your specific application. Hope this helps

Comment: "2 different formatters"? But the formatter is called to format the output that ends up in my `<input>`. How else would I do it? I don't want to change it manually using jQuery; that would be really ugly.

Comment: Sorry I thought for some reason you had two different depdancies, timezone being only one of them, that both were requried to make the one formatter. Please disregard that part.

Comment: No, you had it right. The 2 dependencies are the timezone and the actual ngmodel for the input, which is just the epoch timestamp

Comment: It ended up getting ugly, but in the end, watching it worked. As I said, I did it differently in terms of how I got to the scope element, but this was the right approach. Thanks again.